# Server ram usage increases and crashes the server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

So, I've created Minecraft server with 4GB RAM and 4 core 1Hz CPU on a VDS (Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64).
But there's a huge problem regarding RAM usage.

Over time RAM usage only goes up (with me being the only player). Eventually server runs out of memory and crashes.

I would be greatful to recieve a soultion. Is upgrading ram and making auto-reboot script the only possible fix?
I saw the same problem over the net, but there was no solution.

The command i’m using to start-up the server is:

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=”https://mcflags.emc.gs” -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar server.jar nogui
```

The server starts with 2GB for some reason, then lives for around 2 hours - then crashes.

Comment: In order to help you, we need more information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61459523/edit) the command you are using to start your server into your question. Also, how long does it take from when you start the server till when it crashes?

Comment: Why did you allocate all of the ram to JVM. Did you try to decrease the value?

Comment: 1. The image doesn't show the memory increasing over time, it's only a single point in time. 2. as Kerim noted you should not assign all memory to the Java heap. The operating system itself and the Java process itself still need additional memory in addition to the heap, try giving Java only ~3GB.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are allocating *all* your computer's 4Gbs of RAM to Minecraft. This means that the computer will have no RAM left for other processes.
To fix this issue, try running the server with *less* RAM. For example, try:

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -jar server.jar nogui
```

Start the server with only 1Gb of RAM and set the max RAM to 3Gb so that your computer has 1Gb left for other processes that are running. 
Java will allocate more RAM as needed to the Minecraft server up to 3Gb.

Comment: The question has been edited _after_ this answer was written, FYI voters.